# Hosted apache2 website visible on internet

Tags: apache-httpd, dynamic-dns

I want to know how do I make a website visible on internet hosted in my local machine using apache2 as a web-server. I'm completely new about this topics, and the thing is (just for practice and learn how it works) how can my IP resolve my domain name and once I type it on my browser can redirects me to my website.

I know that once my IP address change, it won't be accesible because, it is a dynamic ip.

Comment: Many ISPs disallow hosting public websites on their networks. Additionally, any kind of traffic may slow your home network down immensely. I would definitely recommend picking up a cheap hosting plan (Digital Ocean offers SSD VPS instances for $5/mo; can't really beat it) and hosting your website there.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad.  There are plenty of tutorials already on the internet if you just search for the right terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buy a domain name from domain register and you need to request your ISP provider for a static IP. Once you got the Domain Name and Static IP, you need to configure A record for the same in DNS server.

Comment: Many Hosting providers available to host the server, but need to be paid more than what we are maintaining in own.